# Trouble installing opencv on mac

Tags: macos, opencv, installation

I'm trying to install OpenCV on mac(OS X 10.11.6) and use xcode 7.3.1.

I have also tried Macports and Homebrew to install OpenCV, but continue to have the same error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::String::deallocate()", referenced from:
      cv::String::~String() in main-d4af45.o
      cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&) in main-d4af45.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

When building my project in xcode I set the value of Header Search Paths for both debug and release to /usr/local/include and Library Search Paths for both debug and release to /usr/local/lib.  The additional linker flags are: -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab

When I run the main.cpp at the terminal, the same `Undefined symbols` error occurs.

My main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << "OpenCV Version" << CV_VERSION << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried changing my xcode "c++ standard library", to libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library) from libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support), but `'unordered_map' file not found` and `lsh_table.h` errors occur, so i stuck with libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support).